# Pseudoscalar current of Majorana fields

Tags: spinors, majorana-fermions, dirac-matrices

Consider a Majorana spinor 
$$
\Phi=\left(\begin{array}{c}\phi\\\phi^\dagger\end{array}\right)
$$
and an pseudoscalar current $\bar\Phi\gamma^5\Phi$. This term is invariant under hermitian conjugation: 
$$
\bar\Phi\gamma^5\Phi\to\bar\Phi\gamma^5\Phi
$$
but if I exploit the two component structure
$$
\bar\Phi\gamma^5\Phi=-\phi\phi+\phi^\dagger\phi^\dagger
$$
the invariance under hermitian conjugation seems lost
$$
-\phi\phi+\phi^\dagger\phi^\dagger\to\phi\phi-\phi^\dagger\phi^\dagger.
$$
Where is the catch?

Comment: Conjugate the individual components then multiply together to cancel out the minus?

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to say, can you be more explicit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found the (silly) error:
$$
\bar\Phi\gamma^5\Phi=\Phi^\dagger\gamma^0\gamma^5\Phi
$$ so under hermitian conjugation this becomes
$$
\Phi^\dagger\gamma^5\gamma^0\Phi=-\Phi^\dagger\gamma^0\gamma^5\Phi=-\bar\Phi\gamma^5\Phi
$$
that imply
$$
\bar\Phi\gamma^5\Phi+h.c.=0
$$
the same result that we found exploiting the two component structure.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should sort out if the components of the spinor are c-numbers or Grassmann numbers in your problem. If they are c-numbers, then the pseudoscalar built on the Majorana spinor vanishes, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Exploiting the indexes the product $\phi\phi$ is 
$$
\phi\phi=\phi^\alpha\phi_\alpha=\phi^\alpha\epsilon_{\alpha\beta}\phi^\beta
$$
where $\epsilon_{\alpha\beta}$ is the usual antisymmetric symbol and $\phi^\alpha$ and $\phi^\beta$ are Grassman numbers. So the product $\phi\phi$ commute.

Comment: @Cervantes: If your components are Grassmann numbers, my answer does not seem relevant, but I don't quite see how your comment is relevant:-)

Comment: What I was trying to say is that even if the component of $\phi$ are Grassmann numbers the product $\phi\phi$ commute as if they are c-numbers.